why will my last two methods in my program not execute
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Unit1;

namespace Unit1
{ 
    class factor
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*****Section 2*****");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number to factorial: ");
            int n2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Factorial anwser " + n2 + " : ");
            //printing Factorial
            for (int i = 1; i <= n2; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(factorial2(i) + " ");
            }
        }

        public static int factorial2(int n2)
        {
            if (n2 == 1)
                return 1;
            else
                return n2 * factorial2(n2 - 1);
        }
       
        public static void Fibonacci(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number up to which Fibonacci series to print: ");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Fibonacci series up to " + number + " numbers : ");
            //printing Fibonacci series upto number
            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(Getfibonacci(i) + " ");
            }
        }

        public static int Getfibonacci(int n)
        {
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (n == 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return (Getfibonacci(n - 1) + Getfibonacci(n - 2));
            }
        }
    }
}

I have tried putting the last two methods in a separate class and they still would not execute. I have also tried calling the last two methods in the static void Main and still could not get them to execute. I am still learning the basics of C# so any help will be much appreciated.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods

Your other methods don't run because they are not called from Main. When your program runs, it runs the Main method. If that doesn't call the other methods, they don't run. Your Main only calls factorial2.
Call Fibonacci as well, which in turn calls Getfibonacci, and you'll see these methods are called, too.
For example, change the end of your Main like this:
              Console.WriteLine("Factorial anwser " + n2 + " : ");
              // printing Factorial
              for (int i = 1; i <= n2; i++)
              {
                  Console.Write(factorial2(i) + " ");
              }
              // printing Fibonacci
              Fibonacci(args);

Or, even better, remove the unused args from Fibonacci:
          public static void Fibonacci() {

and just call it without arguments
             Fibonacci();

in your Main.
